# noise and silence clearing in java

Tags: java, audio

I’m trying to develop an application that is capable of identifying a bird sound from a wav file recording. When creating the database im using another collection of sound clips and am trying to get a unique identification to them. Im planning to do this using FFT.(I don’t have any issues with these concepts) The question is, is it important to clear the noise of these base recording before creating the unique identification? If so, will anyone be able to help me with the  concept of “Zero-crossing rate” and some other technique to clear the sound file for noise and silence.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you identify noise as any different from the desired signal?

Comment: this is actually the issue that i have. I only have the soundclip that has both noise and silence with the bird sound.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no way to remove noise unless you already have an accurate way of indentfying a temporal or spectral difference between the noise and the signal of interest.  For instance, if you know the exact frequency bandwidth of the entire signal of interest, then you can use DSP to filter out the spectrum outside if that bandwidth.  If you know the minimum amplitude of your signal of interest, then you can clip out everything below that level.

Comment: by "clip out" do u mean make them zero or remove them?

Comment: my intention is to get a new byte array without any unnecessary data other than bird sound data so i can get FFT values for a standard window of those data.

Comment: also i dont have an idea about how to get amplitude in the time domain.